# Duality and products

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:\mathcal{A}\longrightarrow\mathcal{B}$ be a functor, assume that both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are complete and cocomplete. I want to prove that the following two conditions are equivalent:

1) $F$ preserves binary products

2) $F$ preserves binary coproducts

My book says that this comes applying duality. But I would like to understand it in practice. Here are my thoughts:

Let's denote with $F^{\operatorname{op}}:\mathcal{A}^{\operatorname{op}}\longrightarrow\mathcal{B}^{\operatorname{op}}$ the functor defined by
$$F^{\operatorname{op}}(A):=F(A)$$
$$F^{\operatorname{op}}(f):=F(f)$$

Assume that $F$ preserves binary products and try to prove that it preserves binary coproducts. Then take a binary coproduct in $\mathcal{A}$. It is a product in $\mathcal{A}^{\operatorname{op}}$ and since $F^{\operatorname{op}}$ is the same as $F$ and $F$ preserves products, it is mapped to a product in $\mathcal{B}^{\operatorname{op}}$, that is into a coproduct of $\mathcal{B}$.

Do you think I am correct? Are there smoother ways to proceed?

Comment: What you're trying to prove seems to be false. Let $A$ be the 4-element Boolen algebra, considered as a poset and thus as a category, and let $B$ be obtained from $A$ by adjoining one more element $z$ below the bottom element 0 of $A$. Both of these posets are finite lattices, hence complete and cocomplete categories. Let $F$ map each element of $A$ to the same element of $B$ except that 0 is mapped to $z$. Then $F$ preserves binary coproducts (joins) but not binary products (meets).

Comment: Do you think that if I add: $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{A}^{\operatorname{op}},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}^{\operatorname{op}}$ all complete and cocomplete then I exclude your counterexample?

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}$ is both complete and cocomplete, than so is its opposite category, so you are not adding any hypotheses...

Comment: I'm curious, what is the book that asks you to prove this? The mistake in your reasoning is that "by duality" you really get that if $F\colon \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ preserves products, then $F\colon \mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op}\to \mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op}$ preserves coproducts.

Comment: @Alejo the book is Handbook of categorical algebra by Borceux vol. 2 but the mistake is mine, since the assumption that the categories are abelian is crucial, as Marco pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is false in general. For, take the forgetful functor $$U\colon\mathbf{Ab}\longrightarrow \mathbf{Set},$$ from the category of abelian groups to the category of sets. Note that both $\mathbf{Ab}$ and $\mathbf{Set}$ are complete and cocomplete, so the same is true of their opposite categories. Now, since the underlying set of the product of two abelian groups $A$, $B$ is the cartesian product of the underlying sets of $A$ and $B$, $U$ preserves (binary) products. However, the coproduct of $A$ and $B$ is their direct sum $A\oplus B$ (which is also their product), whose underlying set is *not* the coproduct of the underlying sets of $A$ and $B$, so $U$ does not preserve (binary) coproducts.

Note: the statement becomes true if you restrict yourself to additive categories and additive functors between them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain me why it becomes true with $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ additive and $F$ additive? More precisely, which features of these particular categories make the result true?

Comment: You are welcome :) In an additive category, binary products and binary coproducts coincide. More precisely, if $A, B$ are objects of an additive category $\mathcal{A}$, every binary product $A\times B$ can be shown to have the universal property of a coproduct of $A$ and $B$ and viceversa. This leads to the notion of biproduct, which you can look up everywhere in the literature. For a functor between additive categories, being additive (i.e. respecting sums) is equivalent to preserving biproducts, whence what you need.

Comment: You can find all of this (and much more) in any textbook on homological algebra which talks about abelian categories. "Categories for the Working Mathematician" would work as well.